# Commenting System in XPages

Tags: xpages

I'm trying to implement a simple comment system in XPages. I have come across examples that create response documents from an existing document. The issue I'm having is when I open a new XPage and want to add a comment but I don't have an existing document because it hasn't been saved yet.

Is there a way I can create comments (response documents) on an unsaved document somehow? Or is there a different way to implement a comment system that doesn't use response documents?

Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is XPages then don't use a response document.  Use a manual key of some sort.  I prefer @Unique style keys - some people use UNIDS.

There's little to no value in using pure response document in XPages applications.

Patrick asks the key question.  How can you have a "child" document if you don't first save the "parent" document.

Now of course you can save the parent and the child at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think what I am going to do is save the parent first and then handle the comment after.

Comment: @David Leedy I am doing the same but unable to save the child document. Fields on xpage are bound with data source. but system is not saving child document at all.

Comment: If you have more then one document datasource bound to the xpage then there's an ignoreRequestParameter setting in there somewhere.  I forget exactly but that usually needs to be set to false for the child dataSource I believe.

Answer (score 2):

A response document need the unid of the main document for creation. If the main document is not saved you get the following exception.

```
Unable to create new document
NotesException: Invalid universal id
```

I don't know an other way to handle this problem.

Why don't you want to save the main document?

Comment: I think I am going to save the parent document first and then handle the comment like you mention. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

How can someone comment on something that does not exist?

I would need more details but you need to save the document. Perhaps you can move it into a different category like a draft view or something till it is ready for production?